# Physically, up to what size is it possible to miniaturize the process node of a silicon chip?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, electrical-engineering, technology

With current technology we have managed to manufacture silicon chips of up to 3 nm for the semiconductor industry. To what size is it physically possible to make smaller the process node for these semiconductors?

Links to contextualize the question:

Process node:
https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/technology_node

3 nm process:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_nm_process

Semiconductor device fabrication:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor_device_fabrication

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note that the "technology node" article you cited says that starting with the one called "22 nm," the numbers in those node names now are meaningless. They no longer denote the physical size of any specific feature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any definite answer for this question, but I want to share some of my opinions about it. Even [imec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMEC) can only predict 2A in 2036.

[image: imec roadmap]

Theoretically, it is possible to build a [single-atom transistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-atom_transistor), but I think what you are asking is not about theoretical possibility, it is about the practical possibility. If you follow up [imec roadmap](https://www.imec-int.com/en/articles/smaller-better-faster-imec-presents-chip-scaling-roadmap), you can see it is quite unlikely we would manufacture single-atom transistor chips in a high volume. In the next 10 years, we will probably go to [CFET (Complementary FET](https://www.imec-int.com/en/articles/imec-puts-complementary-fet-cfet-logic-technology-roadmap)), but such stacked-device chips could have really bad reliability. The channel is entirely surrounded by gate oxides, so the thermal dissipation can be really worse. Such a [self-heating](https://semiengineering.com/self-heating-issues-spread/) can be a severe issue in stacked devices, but I believe CFET is the future, and what really matters now is the number of transistor per unit area, instead of some physical length. After all, people buy iPhone for functionalities based on speed, instead of physical size of transistors. Anyway, the technology nodes like 3nm or 2nm for marketing can sound ridiculous when it becomes 1A or even 0.5A, because we know the atomic radius is around 1A.

Answer (score 1):

At the absolute limit, you are probably asking about [single atom transistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-atom_transistor). As of 2020, single atom transistors made of a [silicone basis with phosphorus as dopant](https://www.nist.gov/news-events/news/2020/05/nist-scientists-create-new-recipe-single-atom-transistors) have been presented by researchers. Since the size of phosphorus and silicone atoms is on the order of 100 picometers, you could argue that a functioning transistor with this choice of materials could be smaller than 1 nanometer, since you still need to close a physical transistor gate and the atoms in the lattice don't "touch" each other at this approx. 100 picometer size boundary.